# Summation Notation Question in McMillan's Theorem Proof

Tags: summation, notation, coding-theory

Let me preface by saying that this question does not pertain as much to coding theory, as it does to mathematical notation. Every symbol in this question is a natural number.

Anyhow, I am currently reading through a proof of McMillan's Theorem. In the proof, there is the statement that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\left( \sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{\alpha_j}{r^j} \right)^u = \left( \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r} + \cdots + \dfrac{\alpha_m}{r^m}  \right)^u, 
\end{equation}

and so far, so good. However, the next line states that $(1)$ out can be multiplied out to yield

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i_j \leq m \\ i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_u}} \dfrac{\alpha_{i_1}}{r^{i_1}} \cdots \dfrac{\alpha_{i_u}}{r^{i_u}} = \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i_j \leq m \\ i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_u}} \dfrac{\alpha_{i_1} \alpha_{i_2} \cdots \alpha_{i_u}}{r^{i_1 + \cdots + i_u}},
\end{equation}

which confuses me. Can someone explain to me what the subscripts on the sigmas in equation $(2)$ are meant to indicate?

Also, I apologize if this question has already been answered somewhere else. I tried to look through the archives and didn't come across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid clutter, let

$$f(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_u)=\frac{\alpha_1}{r^{i_1}}\cdot\frac{\alpha_2}{r^{i_2}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{\alpha_u}{r^{i_u}}\;.\tag{1}$$

(It could just as well be any function of $u$ variables.) Then

$$\sum_{\substack{1\le i_j\le m\\i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_u}}f(i_1,\ldots,i_u)\tag{2}$$

is the sum of the values $f(i_1,\ldots,i_u)$ as $\langle i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_u\rangle$ ranges over all $u$-tuples of integers satisfying the condition that $1\le i_j\le m$ for $j=1,\ldots,u$. For example, if $u=3$ and $m=2$, we have

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{\substack{1\le i_j\le 2\\i_1,i_2,i_3}}f(i_1,i_2,i_3)&=f(1,1,1)+f(1,1,2)+f(1,2,1)+f(1,2,2)\\
&\quad+f(2,1,1)+f(2,1,2)+f(2,2,1)+f(2,2,2)\;.
\end{align*}$$

In general there will be $m^u$ terms in the sum, since each of the $u$ indices $i_j$ can take any of the $m$ values from $1$ through $m$.

When you multiply out

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{\alpha_j}{r^j}\right)^u=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{\alpha_j}{r^j}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{\alpha_j}{r^j}\right)}_{u\text{ copies}}\;,\tag{3}$$

each term of the product (before you collect like terms) is the product of fractions $\frac{\alpha_j}{r^j}$, one from each of the $u$ copies, so it has exactly the form of our $f(i_1,\ldots,i_u)$ in $(1)$. $(2)$ is the sum of all of these terms, so it’s equal to $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

\begin{align}
    \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 \dfrac{\alpha_j}{r^j} \right)^3 
    &= \left( \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r}+\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2} \right)^3 \\
    &= \left( \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}+\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2} \right)
       \left( \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}+\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2} \right)
      \left( \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}+\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2} \right) \\
    &= \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}+\\
       &\phantom{=} \left(
          \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}+
          \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}+
          \dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}
      \right) +\\
      &\phantom{=} \left(
          \dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}+
          \dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}+
          \dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_1}{r^1}
          \right) + \\
       &\phantom{=}
        \dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\dfrac{\alpha_2}{r^2}\\
    &= \dfrac{\alpha_1\alpha_1\alpha_1}{r^{1+1+1}} + \\
    &\phantom{=} \left(
       \dfrac{\alpha_1\alpha_1\alpha_2}{r^{1+1+2}}+
       \dfrac{\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_1}{r^{1+2+1}}+
       \dfrac{\alpha_2\alpha_1\alpha_1}{r^{2+1+1}}
   \right) +\\
   &\phantom{=} \left(
       \dfrac{\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_2}{r^{1+2+2}}+
       \dfrac{\alpha_2\alpha_1\alpha_2}{r^{r^2+1+2}}+
       \dfrac{\alpha_2\alpha_2\alpha_1}{r^{r^2+2+1}}
       \right) + \\
    &\phantom{=} \dfrac{\alpha_2\alpha_2\alpha_2}{r^{2+2+2}} \\
\end{align}